# combining elements of matrix in groups of 4 without repetition

Tags: python, combinations

I am a new member of this community and a new user of Python.

I am facing a little problem, both at conceptual and at coding level. It is the following:

I have 11 groups of the 8 identical elements (in real life they are 2 cotton pads cut in 4 pieces each, for a total number of 8 pieces, multiplied for 11 donors - it is a body odor collection study), namely:

A A A A A A A A 
B B B B B B B B 
C C C C C C C C 
...
M M M M M M M M

I have now to form a supra-donor pad by combining 4 different-donor pieces, e.g. ABCD, ABCE, CDEF etc... The new groups of 4 elements shouldn't contain pieces from the same donor (e.g. AABC or ABDD are not allowed) and of course if a piece is used, then it can't be used to form another supra-donor pad.
I wanted to code something that allowed the groups formation automatically, without hitting my head to do it manually, risking to lose count of it.

Is this a case of combinations without repetitions?
I was thinking in doing something like: create a matrix like the one above, create 20 (the number of supra-donor pads I need) 4-elements empty groups (lists?) and then a loop in which I tell to randomly pick the Cij element of the matrix and move it in the empty list, then go on to the next element to pick, but being sure that it is a different type and a piece that was not pick in a previous group (e.g. if a group has element C43, then that same element shouldn't be used in another group). Do so until the 4-element group is full and then move to the next 4-element group

I am asking some help because I have little time to do this, otherwise I would try to learn by making loads of mistakes. 
Any suggestion?

EDIT: example of a table with the 4-element groups already created and the number of eighth-part parts used for the different elements used (some of them will be in advance, of course)

[supra-donor pads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDFok.png)

Thank you in advance to everyone willing to provide insights!

Comment: Could you give an example of some sample inputs and expected results? I think the itertools builtins might be enough

Comment: Hi @JackEvans, thanks for the quick response. I attached an image of the ending results, if that can answer your question. thanks again

Comment: Do you have any requirements of picking approximately equally many from each group?

Comment: @JohanL : Hi JonahL, thanks for the useful question. Having an approximately equal number of pads from each group would be the best approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that generates all possible combinations of the donors, then shuffles them and picks a new one in every iteration. If the picked one is not valid, due to all samples of the picked donor is already exhausted, that combination is dropped and a new one is chosen.

```
import itertools
import random

def comb_generator(bases, per_base, sought):
    combs = list(itertools.combinations(bases, 4))
    random.shuffle(combs)

    avail = {}
    for base in bases:
        avail[base] = per_base

    comb_wanted = sought > 0 # Ensure picking at least one new comb
    while comb_wanted:
        comb = combs.pop()
        comb_wanted = False

        for base in comb:
            comb_wanted = avail[base] <= 0
            if comb_wanted:
                break

        if not comb_wanted:
            for base in comb:
                avail[base] -= 1
            yield comb
            sought -= 1
            comb_wanted = sought > 0

bases = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'
per_base = 8
sought = 20

comb_gens = comb_generator(bases, per_base, sought)

for i, comb in enumerate(comb_gens):
    print('{:2}: {}'.format(i, comb))
```

As can be seen, I have implemented the solution as a generator, since I find that to be rather useful when later on working with the entries.

N.B. The current solution does not care about keeping an equal number of samples from each donor. That could be done by adding a requirement on the availability of different donors to not vary too much. But it would add to the complexity, where discarded combinations are re-inserted, at a later position in the 'deck'.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you so much!